# Magento Integration With Local Courier

Tags: shipment-tracking

I need to integrate our "Leopard Courier" (Local Courier) with magento 1.9.2.3. Our Leopard Courier also give us "APi Documents" but i don't under stand. We also have "API  KEY and Password" receive from leopard courier. 
I don't know how can i integrate with magento. Our case is this from magento backend there must be a link "Generate the tracking Code or Generate Label" than its automatically connect to the leopard courier and take the tracking number from them and generate the print of 3 copies

1. Customer Copy
2. Account Copy
3. Label.

Mention on the print are :

1. Tracking Code
2. Magento Order Number
3. Customer Name
4. Address
5. Desination
6. Mob Number
7. Weight
8. Cash Collection Amount
9. Date
10. Shipper AC /Name
11. Shipper Address.

Comment: You need to create new module for your shipping carrier and integrate all your needed API in it. for reference you can check  files

app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Abstract.php
app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment.. How can i make new module. which file i need to edit. basically i am new to use magento 1.9.2.3.? Can you please explain me in details the steps for implementing this?

Comment: you need to understand module creation steps and how magento work for basic step check [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) for more information google it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the extension of Leopards Courier for Magento 1 directly from Leopards. After installing extension you have to add the api key for generating cities.
You will get a document with complete user guide with extension from Leopards.